# Tabulator grid Refresh question on data call

Tags: javascript, spring, tabulator

I am using ajax to call data.

I set it up as follows.

```
function getTestList(){
  testTable = new Tabulator("#test_list", {
  height:"550px",
  layout:"fitColumns",
  selectable:true, //row Select
  reactiveData:true,
  rowContextMenu: headerMenu, //add context menu to rows
  headerHozAlign:"center",
  ajaxConfig:"POST",
  ajaxLoader:false,
  ajaxURL:"/test/testListDetail",
  ajaxProgressiveLoad:"scroll",
  ......
 });
}
```

1. Call the "getTestList()" function when the page is loaded.
2. After registering and modifying data
   "testTable.replaceData();" You are running the method.
3. The data in the table is being reloaded after refreshing.

http://tabulator.info/examples/4.9?#adddel

What I want to achieve is that the data is updated without a refresh like in the example above.
I am fetching data from the current server. Is there a way to fetch the data without blinking?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are rebuilding the table every time you call that function. That is not the correct approach.

You should build the table once when the page loads, then when you want to update the data, simply call the `setData` function and it will run the request again without needing to rebuild the table:

```js
testTable.setData();
```

If you want the scroll position of the table to remain in place while the data is reloaded, u can use the `replaceData` function:

```js
testTable.replaceData();
```